# How can I feed my ndarray data to the TensorShape input of the basic Keras model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, input, keras, numpy-ndarray

I want to feed data to the basic keras model. The input has the following shape and type. I do not know if I made the wrong settings in the model layer, but I get the following error.

My environmnet is Windows 10 (64-bits), Python 3.6.7 (Anaconda), TensorFlow 1.12.0, Keras 2.2.4, PyCharm 2018.3.3.

Input:

x input shape: `(23714, 160)`, y input shape: `(23714, 7)`

```
In: x
Out:
array([[ 7, 19,  6, ...,  0,  0,  0],
       [11,  1, 16, ...,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6, 13, 10, ...,  0,  0,  0],
       ...,
       [ 6, 13,  7, ...,  0,  0,  0],
       [11, 13,  9, ..., 10,  0,  0],
       [ 9, 13,  9, ...,  0,  0,  0]])
```

```
In: y
Out: 
array([[0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

Model:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=(160, ), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(7, activation="softmax"))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
performance_test = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=100)
print(model.summary())
print('Test Loss and Accuracy ->', performance_test)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 141, in make_shape
    shape = tensor_shape.as_shape(v)
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 947, in as_shape
    return TensorShape(shape)
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 542, in __init__
    self._dims = [as_dimension(d) for d in dims_iter]
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 542, in <listcomp>
    self._dims = [as_dimension(d) for d in dims_iter]
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 482, in as_dimension
    return Dimension(value)
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 37, in __init__
    self._value = int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-721312fb06f9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/terry/Desktop/Project/Test/Test.py', wdir='C:/Users/terry/Desktop/Project/Test')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/terry/Desktop/Project/Test/Test.py", line 187, in <module>
    model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=(160, ), activation='relu'))
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 161, in add
    name=layer.name + '_input')
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py", line 178, in Input
    input_tensor=tensor)
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py", line 87, in __init__
    name=self.name)
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 517, in placeholder
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1747, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 6250, in placeholder
    shape = _execute.make_shape(shape, "shape")
  File "C:\Users\terry\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 143, in make_shape
    raise TypeError("Error converting %s to a TensorShape: %s." % (arg_name, e))
TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'.
```

I've read about keras `input_shape`, `input_dim`, tensorflow `tensorshape`, python `tuple`, `list`, numpy `ndarray`, but I can not find a solution. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the parameter to `Dense` should be `input_shape` and not `input_dim`. Refer the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense)

Comment: I really appreciate you. I was worried about this problem and tried different methods, but it only works if I change `input_dim` to `input_shape`.

Comment: Another option for clarity would be to begin the Sequential with model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(160,)))

Comment: @TheLoneDeranger Thanks for telling me to use `InputLayer`.

Comment: And I have another question. I know that if I use RNN, LSTM, or GRU, I need to do `data = data.reshape (data.shape [0], 1, data.shape [1])`. However, I wonder if there is a problem when using reshape with `dense` and `conv1d` together.

Comment: Yes, you can reshape, then send to Dense and Conv1d layers; that should work fine. Depending on how the data moves through your network, you may need to use Conv1d parameters like `padding='same'` to maintain data shape, etc. Be sure to use model.summary() to see how each layer changes shape, and that'll help with connecting layers.